# Deploying playframework application on Jboss AS 7.1

Tags: playframework, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy a playframework application on a Jboss AS 7.1 but I am experiecing some difficulties which I tried to find a solution for but I couldn't. So first of all I am building the war file with the play2war plugin - https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

After I try to deploy the application the problems come- the server says the context is initialized, but the deployment fails(from time time the server also throws a strange BufferOverflowError). So here is the log:

```
 23:50:28,255 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 2760ms - Started 133 of 205 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 70 services are passive or on-demand)
 23:50:42,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS014900: Content added at location E:\dev_tools\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\data\content\d7\a090a1f99ee107b2847f47b1c9685f4db3811f\content
 23:50:49,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "texttocopy.war"
 23:51:00,758 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/E:/dev_tools/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/texttocopy.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail.mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
 23:51:00,763 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xbean.jar in "/E:/dev_tools/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/texttocopy.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.xmlgraphics.batik-js-1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
 23:51:00,775 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/E:/dev_tools/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/texttocopy.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.serializer-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
 23:51:00,779 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/E:/dev_tools/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/texttocopy.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
 23:51:00,781 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/E:/dev_tools/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/texttocopy.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
 23:51:00,784 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/E:/dev_tools/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/texttocopy.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
 23:51:01,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).
 23:51:01,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
 23:51:01,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
 23:51:01,601 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010402: Unable to instantiate driver class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.texttocopy_war is already registered
 23:51:01,695 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/texttocopy]] (MSC service thread 1-5) PlayServletWrapper > contextInitialized
```

The error from the admin console is:

```
2014-05-13 23:53:21,590 [ERROR] Message{conciseMessage='Unknown error', detailedMessage='Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "texttocopy.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>        
{"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./texttocopy" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./texttocopy: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}, "rolled-back" => true
}
```

The standalone.xml is with the default configuration- I haven't changed anything there. So if someone can helm me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem is that the play logger is not "playing" very well with the jboss one so all the application logs are lost. So here is a solution directly from the author of the play2war plugin:

Here is a new dependency to include in your project to disable Play Logger:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // ... Actual dependencies
  "com.github.play2war.ext" %% "redirect-playlogger" % "1.0.1" // add this after your others dependencies
)
```

How does it work ?
Play logger configuration is disabled, that is to say project's logger.xml file will be ignored.
So logs have to be configured by your app server (JBoss for eg.).